# xml reader in asp mvc

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have read rss feed by below function

```
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(feedUri.AbsoluteUri))
```

but sometimes, when the URL is not valid (404) it shows error. how can I validate the URL before read it with this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `catch` block and handle the `WebException` as desired.